# Should we say "todo Colombia" or "toda Colombia"?

Tags: concordancia-gramatical

I have heard the following sentence said by the Colombian president in Narcos (a TV series which takes place in Colombia):

> Eso es una verguenza para **todo** Colombia.

Shouldn't "toda" be used instead of "todo", so that it agrees with the feminine noun "Colombia"?

Comment: You could think of it like "the whole of Colombia."  Note that "I'm all ears" becomes "Soy todo oídos," because "todo" here is an adverb meaning *completely*.

Comment: Referencia de por qué Colombia es femenina [Género de los nombres de países y ciudades](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg): _En la asignación de género a los nombres propios de países y ciudades influye sobre todo la terminación, aunque son muy frecuentes las vacilaciones. En general puede decirse que los nombres de países que terminan en -a átona concuerdan en femenino con los determinantes y adjetivos que los acompañan_.

Comment: @aparente001 That logic doesn’t really work with ‘completely Colombia’, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - That is why translating is an art. // I'm sorry, when I said "here," I was referring to "Soy todo oídos."

Comment: We as colombians think of the country as masculine.I know that argentinians talk about "la Argentina" and brazilians use "el Brazil" but we never even think of "la Colombia" or "el Colombia". Some of my friends from Brazil use "la Colombia" because they see it as "la República de Colombia" but we think about it more like "el país"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [género en ciudades y países](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/genero-en-ciudades-y-paises/) from Fundéu:

> 5. Cuando se antepone ***todo***, el género alterna en todos los nombres de ciudades: *todo Bogotá* o *toda Bogotá*. En España y México, se emplea el giro *el todo*, siempre masculino, para referirse a la élite social: *el todo Barcelona*.

and [¿Es toda Europa o todo Europa?](http://udep.edu.pe/castellanoactual/es-toda-europa-o-todo-europa/) from Castellano Actual:

> Finalmente, cuando los topónimos acabados en *-a* se combinan con el cuantificador ***todo***, admiten tanto la concordancia femenina como la masculina (*todo/toda Europa*; *todo/toda Venezuela*); aunque se prefiere el femenino.

Though Colombia is a feminine noun, when the word *todo* comes before a country or city, both *todo* and *toda* are acceptable.

In Spain, I hear *toda España* much more often than *todo España*. (I also have never heard that construction *el todo Barcelona*).